# dial tcp 10.97.138.229:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

> Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress-srv.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.97.138.229:443: connect: connection refused

I am new to Kubernetes, I was setting up ingress nginx on **Docker Desktop for windows** and it installed successfully but when I try to run using kubectl apply -f filename it gives above error

here is the code filename: **ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
         - path: /posts
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: posts-srv
               port:
                 number: 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io"

This suggests that you did deploy your ingress nginx controller, and some bits are not starting up.

At that stage, you should look at Pods, in the namespace where your ingress controller is deployed. It is likely those ingress Pods are not starting or unhealthy.

You won't be able to create Ingresses, until your done setting up your ingress controller.